# how does this java byte conversion work

Tags: java

```
int port = data[4] << (24 & 0xFF000000);//data[]=byte array containing int value
port = port | ((data[3] << 16) & 0x00FF0000);

port = port | ((data[2] << 8) & 0x0000FF00);

port = port | (data[1] & 0x000000FF);
```

I am new to bit level. Can somebody explain how this byte conversion works and what will be the result.

Comment: The brackets in the first line do not match the pattern in the other lines...

Comment: Yes, the first line evaluates to `data[4]`, which is probably not the right thing, but I'm also suspicious of the indexes - arrays are supposed to start at 0 (though it's possible that context would make this reasonable). If you're trying to learn from that code, don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The int as well as the other integer primitives(in java) are stored using the 2's complement number representation ([link here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)).That means that if your number will be represented on 31 bits as normal if it is positive and you would have to find the "complemet from 2^32 if is negative.
In the languages that accept unsigned variables the conversion into binary is the one you would probably expect, the normal base conversion of 32 bits. Before this you might want to read [this](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap03/logical.html) if you are not familiar with logical operators.
For your case you store a 4 byte array (32 bits is the length of an int) and do the following operations:

1. `port = data[4] << (24 & 0xF000)` : port is equal to the last byte in the array because `24 = 0x0018 (16 + 8)` in hexa, `&` means logical and, therefore `24 & 0xF000 = 0`, now `data[4] << 0` is data[4] on first byte (shifting bits 0 times)  `port = Ox000(data[4])`
2. next we have `port = port | ((data[3] << 16) & 0x0F00)` which changes nothing again but the one byte from position 16 with `data[3]` (the second byte). That is because shifting 16 bits to the left and than making logical bitwise AND with `0x0F00` will just keep those bits from where we have `F`(1 bit). Then bitwise | with port will just add 1's where you had 0 from the position the number we were just discussing. `port = 0x0(data[3])0(data[4])`. 
   edit : 0x00FF0000 is actually 0x0F00 because it will be interpreted as an int not a long (64 bits)). I would not recommand you to use this type of code, it is tricky to see the long truncation and also  because of endiannes (the way the machine interpretes the data, the order of the bytes). Java was created for platform independence and in this case the JVM might figure out (I have to document myself on that as well) and rescue you but in another lower level languages it isn't like that. 
   Do the same with the other two and find out how those bits are playing around

Comment: After using Integer.toBinaryString to find out those are the truncated masks you were doing logical and on: 
`0xFF000000` will be transformed to `0xF000`  , `0x00FF0000` to `0x0F00`, `0x0000FF00` to `0x00F0` , `0x000000FF` to `0x000F`. Now do the logic from above using those numbers

Comment: thanks, So by this code, the last line of code should overwrite the content of data[4] with data[1] right, making it port=0x0(data[3])(data[2])(data[1]) ?

Comment: Also why is it necessary to pass the values in hex, will there be any difference if i change the line "port | (data[1] & 0x000000FF)" to "port | (data[1] & 255)"

Comment: I will come with a more complete solution, considering that JVM is Big Endian and the unintened long truncation mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I mistakenly taught that 8 hexa decimals as not a integer,that is false, the way it is written is correct.

1. `int port = data[4] << (24 & 0xFF000000)` Here 24 will be converted to `0x0000018 & 0xFF000000 = 0`, therefore `data[4]` will be kept on the last position.
2. `port = port | ((data[3] << 16) & 0x00FF0000)` Here `data[3]` will be shifted by 2 bytes , then `0x00(data[3])0000 & 0x00FF0000` is equal to 
   `0x00(data[3])0000` and after we make an `|` with the original port we get 
   `port = 0x00(data[3])00(data[4])`.
3. `port = port | ((data[2] << 8) & 0x0000FF00)` Here `data[2]` will be shifted by 1 byte and we will get `0x0000(data[2])00 = 0x0000(data[2])00 & 0x0000FF00` and attach it to get `port = 0x00(data[3])(data[2])(data[4])`
4. `port = port | (data[1] & 0x000000FF)` Here youl will have as a result `port = 0x00(data[3])(data[2])(data[1] | data[4])`. Probably this was not intended because you mix up those numbers, most likely you wanted to shift 24 bytes `data[4]` in the first place. Don't get confused if that number will be negative because of the 2's complement number representation.